# Get GeoJSON files hosted on AWS S3 to work in Leaflet inside JavaScript

Tags: leaflet, geojson

Is there a way to call an AWS GeoJSON file from leaflet and not get CORS errors?  I took the advice of putting **"var Flight ="** at the beginning of a GeoJSON  file and saving it as JavaScript. I have a map that works when I call the GeoJSON (as .sj) like this

```
<script src="https://myflights.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/2023_0322/images/2023_0322.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and then later using it with the variable **"Flight"**

```
var leftPoints = L.geoJSON(Flight, {
      pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) { 
         label = String(feature.properties.Name)
         return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonGreen).bindTooltip(label, {permanent: false, opacity: 0.75}).openTooltip();
         },
      onEachFeature: popUpLFeature}).addTo(map1);
```

my issue is when I try to change this using a variable to define the url: inside JavaScript and then trying to load the GeoJSON.

I have tried `JQuery.getScript` and `$getJson` but always end up with a CORS error.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at "https://myflights.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/2023_0322/images/2023_0322.js" from origin 'https://my-test-2.azurewebsites.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have tried methods mentioned here - [How to get Leaflet layer control to work with GeoJSON files hosted online](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207352/how-to-get-leaflet-layer-control-to-work-with-geojson-files-hosted-online) but this seems to give the same result.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50022326/amazon-s3-image-cors-issue

Comment: That Worked!!  Thank You @TomazicM.